# How to add Annotation tags to a String programmatically

Tags: java, android, kotlin, annotations, android-spannable

In [this video](https://youtu.be/x-FcOX6ErdI?t=793) Google gave an example for formatting portions of a `String` based on [`Annotation`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Annotation) tags that can be used to set a key/value pairs in a `String` within `strings.xml`.

Here is an example for this:

**strings.xml**

```
<string name="test">Hello <annotation font="sans-serif-medium">World!</annotation></string>
```

Kotlin Code:

```
val spannedString = getText(R.string.title) as SpannedString
val annotations = spannedString.getSpans(0, spannedString.length, Annotation::class.java)
for (annotation in annotations) {
    if (annotation.key == "font") {
        val fontName = annotation.value
        val typeFace: Typeface = ...
        spannable.setSpan(TypefaceSpan(typeFace), abstract.getSpanStart(annotation),
                abstract.getSpanEnd(annotation), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE)
    }
}
```

This also has been used with [`ReplacementSpan`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/ReplacementSpan.html) in [this article](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/drawing-a-rounded-corner-background-on-text-5a610a95af5) to tackle the problem of the `ReplacementSpans` that they can not flow into the next line of text.

**My Question is:**

I need to create/remove Annotation tags dynamically so that I can programmatically remove tags from portions of text that are marked with annotation tags or add tags to non-annotated text.

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally we attach `String` spans with an implementation of [`ParcelableSpan`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/ParcelableSpan) like [`ForegroundColorSpan`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/ForegroundColorSpan), [`BackgroundColorSpan`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/BackgroundColorSpan#summary), [`UnderlineSpan`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/UnderlineSpan), [`TypefaceSpan`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/TypefaceSpan) .. etc

And by observing that the [`Annotation`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Annotation) also implements `ParcelableSpan` as well, we can use [`setSpan()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Spannable#setSpan(java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int,%20int)) to attach annotation to it, and add the key/value pairs to [its constructor](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Annotation#Annotation(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)).

My other observation is that [`setSpan()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Spannable#setSpan(java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int,%20int)) actually accepts an `Object` as a first argument.

So referring to the referenced question [article](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/drawing-a-rounded-corner-background-on-text-5a610a95af5) example ([GitHub Repo](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-text/tree/master/RoundedBackground-Kotlin)); to set annotation programmatically:

```
val span = SpannableString("value \n 1 Some Value Value 2")
span.setSpan(Annotation("", "rounded"), 0, 10, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE)
span.setSpan(Annotation("", "rounded"), 15, 19, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE)

textView.text = span
```

The key of the `Annotation` doesn't matter in this example, as we only need its tag/value. So kept it as an empty String.

**The result:**

[image]